# Does Google Analytics to BigQuery continuous refresh wait until the session is closed?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Recently [Google announced streaming data into BigQuery](https://analytics.googleblog.com/2017/09/new-streaming-google-analytics-data-for.html) from Google Analytics. This cuts down the data refresh time from 3 times a day to a continuous refresh every 10-15 minutes. My questions is, does the continuous refresh wait until the user's session is closed before it sends it into BigQuery? or does it send partial session data into BigQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to confirm, after activating the continuous refresh setting, that GA does NOT wait until the session is complete to send data to BigQuery. So you will see partial session data in BigQuery.

[Boom.](https://media.giphy.com/media/OcZp0maz6ALok/200.gif)